# How to use grails pagination if the list is already provided?

Tags: grails, pagination

I have a method that looks like this

```
def searchInAllField(String searchString) {

    Long companyId = sessionService.userProfile.companyId;
    return Vendor.createCriteria().list(){

        eq("companyId", companyId);
        if (searchString) {
            or {
                ilike("name", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("businessName", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("address", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("description", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("contactPerson", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("mobileNumber", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("officeNumber", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("email", "%${searchString}%")
            }
        }
        order("businessName", "asc");

    } ?: [];
}
```

This method accepts searchString parameter and check if it matches the value in all field.

The result of this method is a list which needs to be displayed and put a pagination. How can I put a grails pagination if I already have the list?

Answer (score 1):

To use pagination your `searchInAllField()` method needs to incorporate `max` and `offset` parameters.

```
def searchInAllField(String searchString, int max, int offset) {

    Long companyId = sessionService.userProfile.companyId;
    return Vendor.createCriteria().list(max: max, offset: offset) {

        eq("companyId", companyId);
        if (searchString) {
            or {
                ilike("name", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("businessName", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("address", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("description", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("contactPerson", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("mobileNumber", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("officeNumber", "%${searchString}%")
                ilike("email", "%${searchString}%")
            }
        }
        order("businessName", "asc")

    }
}
```

The controller method which calls `searchInAllField()` will need to pass `max` and `offset` along and provide a total count in the model:

```
def someControllerMethod() {
    def vendors = whatever.searchInAllField(searchString, params.max, params.offset)

    render(model: [vendors: vendors, totalVendors: vendors.totalCount])
}
```

The total count, in this case `vendors.totalCount`, is important. The `g:paginate` taglib needs this to function correctly.

*Note: The [g:paginate](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/paginate.html) documentation can mislead you. It demonstrates using `DomainClass.count()` as the total count. What you want is the **query result** count not the total number of records in the database table. The `totalCount` property provides what you need, but you only get the property when you execute the query with `offset` and `max`.*

Finally, you can use the `g:paginate` taglib in your GSP code to render the pagination links:

```
<g:paginate controller="someController" action="someControllerMethod" total="${totalVendors}" />
```